# Калькулятор в Lazarus

Tags: pascal, lazarus, delphi

Помогите реализовать следующую функцию калькулятора: вычисление "цепочки" операций. Например, при нажатии клавиш в следующем порядке: `5 - 1 = = =` финальный результат равен 2. У меня же получилась только цепочка такого вида: `5 * = = =` (заместо 5 и знака "*" могут быть другие допустимые числа и знаки операций). Прилагаю код процедуры, срабатывающий при нажатии на клавишу "=":

```
procedure TFrm.BtnRsltClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if err then exit;
  if (oper = ' ') then
    begin
      res := op1;
      EdtNmbr.Text := FloatToStr(res);
      exit;
    end;
  if edit then
    begin
      TryStrToFloat(EdtNmbr.Text, op2);
      if i = 1 then
        res := Calculation(op1, op2, oper);
    end
  else
    begin
     if (op_m <> op1) or (oper_m <> oper) then
        i := 1;
      if i = 1 then
        begin
          op_m := op1;
          oper_m := oper;
          res := op1;
        end;
      res := Calculation(res, op1, oper);
      inc(i);
    end;
   EdtNmbr.Text := FloatToStr(res);
   edit := false;
end;           `
```

Идея кода такова: существует булевская переменная `edit`, отвечающая за поле редактирования. Если истина, то при нажатии цифр дописываем в конце цифру, если ложь, то полностью заменяем текст на цифру. По ней я и определяю, началась ли цепочка вычислений или нет (при нажатии на клавишу операции она (переменная) становится ложью, чтобы второй операнд не сливался со вторым). Затем есть переменная целого типа `i` - по ней я определяю, какая операция по счету: если первая, то запоминаю операцию и операнд. В следующий раз при нажатии на клавишу "=" идет проверка: если операнд и операция совпадают с предыдущими, то началась "цепочка". Если что-либо изменилось, то это уже другая "цепочка" вычислений, поэтому сбрасываем `i`. Данный код работает только для цепочки с первым операндом и знаком. А как сделать так, чтобы он работал для двух операндов?

Answer (score 2):

Если Ваш калькулятор представляет что-то более серьезное, чем работу с двумя значениями, то используйте обратную польскую запись. Записав выражение в ней, уже не будет проблемы найти терминирующий элемент выражения и сделать операцию повтора.

Answer (score 1):

У меня получился такой калькулятор:

Сперва объявим глобальные переменные в разделе var

```
  First, Second: Extended;
  Operation, OldOperation: Char;
  WasCount, Selected, Count, Counted: Boolean;
```

Затем объявляем 2 процедуры в разделе private:

```
 private
    { private declarations }
    Procedure AddDigit(Sender: TObject); // для добавления цифры
    Procedure SelectOperation(Sender: TObject); // для выбора операции
```

Напишем их код. Добавляем цифру в Edit:

```
procedure TCalculatorForm.AddDigit(Sender: TObject);
begin
  If (EditCalc.Text='0') Then
    If ((Sender As TButton).Caption=DecimalSeparator) Then
      Begin
        If (Selected) Then
          Begin
           EditCalc.Text:='0,';
           Selected:=False;
          End
        Else
           EditCalc.Text:=EditCalc.Text+DecimalSeparator;
        (Sender As TButton).Enabled:=False;
      End
    Else
      EditCalc.Text:=(Sender As TButton).Caption
  Else
    If (((Sender As TButton).Caption=DecimalSeparator)) Then
      Begin
        If (Selected) Then
          Begin
           EditCalc.Text:=(Sender As TButton).Caption;
           Selected:=False;
          End
        Else
            EditCalc.Text:=EditCalc.Text+(Sender As TButton).Caption;
        (Sender As TButton).Enabled:=False;
      End
    Else
        If (Selected) Then
          Begin
           EditCalc.Text:=(Sender As TButton).Caption;
           Selected:=False;
          End
        Else
            EditCalc.Text:=EditCalc.Text+(Sender As TButton).Caption;
end;
```

Выбираем действие:

```
procedure TCalculatorForm.SelectOperation(Sender: TObject);
Var
  StrText: String;
begin
  If (Selected) Then Exit;

  If Not(ButtonDot.Enabled) Then ButtonDot.Enabled:=True;

  If (Counted) Then
    Begin
      Operation:=(Sender As TButton).Caption[1];
      Selected:=True;
      Counted:=False;
      Exit;
    End;

  If (Count) Then
    Begin
         Second:=StrToFloat(EditCalc.Text);
         If (WasCount) Then
           Begin
             OldOperation:=Operation;
             Operation:=(Sender As TButton).Caption[1];

             Case OldOperation Of
              '+': First:=First+Second;
              '-': First:=First-Second;
              '*': First:=First*Second;
              '/': First:=First/Second;
             End;
           End
         Else
           Begin
             Case Operation Of
              '+': First:=First+Second;
              '-': First:=First-Second;
              '*': First:=First*Second;
              '/': First:=First/Second;
             End;
             WasCount:=True;
             Operation:=(Sender As TButton).Caption[1];
           End;

         EditCalc.Text:=FloatToStr(First);
         EditCalc.Repaint;
         Selected:=True;
    End
  Else
      Begin
        Operation:=(Sender As TButton).Caption[1];
        StrText:=EditCalc.Text;
        EditCalc.Text:='';
        EditCalc.Repaint;
        Sleep(200);
        EditCalc.Text:=StrText;
        EditCalc.Repaint;
        First:=StrToFloat(EditCalc.Text);
        Selected:=True;
        Count:=True;
        WasCount:=False;
      End;
  end;
```

Создадим обработчик OnCreate для формы, чтобы задать значения флагов

```
procedure TCalculatorForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Counted:=False; // равно ещё не нажимали
  WasCount:=False; // первое действие ещё не выбрано
{ставим разделитель: точка или запятая - это зависит от настроек системы,
поэтому используем переменную DecimalSeparator (объявлять не надо!)}
  ButtonDot.Caption:=DecimalSeparator;
end;
```

А теперь свяжем наши процедуры с кнопками для этого достаточно на одной из кнопок, которая добавляет цифру (или разделитель) его написать в событии OnClick и передать это событие остальным кнопкам. Например, для кнопки, добавляющей 0:

```
procedure TCalculatorForm.Button0Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AddDigit(Sender);
end;
```

Точно также делаем со всеми кнопками для действий (+, -, *, /). Я выбрал плюс:

```
procedure TCalculatorForm.ButtonPlusClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SelectOperation(Sender);
end;
```

Обработчик для кнопки "равно":

```
procedure TCalculatorForm.ButtonResultClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  If Not (Counted) Then
    Begin
      Second:=StrToFloat(EditCalc.Text);
      Counted:=True;
    End;
  Case Operation Of
       '+': First:=First+Second;
       '-': First:=First-Second;
       '*': First:=First*Second;
       '/': First:=First/Second;
  End;

  EditCalc.Text:=FloatToStr(First);
  EditCalc.Repaint;
  If (Selected) Then Selected:=False;
end;
```

И, наконец, обработчик для кнопки "сброс":

```
procedure TCalculatorForm.ButtonCeClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  EditCalc.Text:='0';
  If Not(ButtonDot.Enabled) Then
     ButtonDot.Enabled:=True;
  First:=0;
  Second:=0;
  If (WasCount) Then WasCount:=False;
  If (Selected) Then Selected:=False;
  If (Counted) Then Counted:=False;
  If (Count) Then Count:=False;
end;
```